# Getting rid of certain configuration messages

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

Just got my first smartphone and I've been trying to get rid of configuration messages that my provider sent me. The problem is that i got sent too many of those, I've installed the ones I needed but I don't know how to get rid of the extra ones. If anyone has any advice how to do that, it would be appreciated. I've been thinking of restoring the phone to factory settings?

It's a samsung S4.

Thanks

Comment: Aren't those sent by SMS? So why can't you simply delete them? Try long-pressing such a message, which should popup a context menu allowing you to delete the message. With some message apps, this even fades in check-boxes to tick, so you can delete multiple messages at once.

Comment: Hello, much appreciated m8. I did as you suggested and I got rid of the messages!

Comment: Glad to read! I've made it an answer (with some more details). As it solved your issue, it would be nice if you "accept" the answer (by ticking the check-mark next to it) – so future visitors can easily identify this issue has a solution. Thanks, and enjoy your cleaned-up device :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those configuration messages are sent as SMS, so you'll find them in your messaging application – where you simply can delete them:

Usually, long-pressing on a single message opens a popup-menu, which a.o. holds an item to "delete" the message. Hit that. With some message apps, this reveals check-boxes next to each message in the "thread", which you can tick before hitting the final "delete" button – and gone they are.

You might also be able to long-press the entire "thread" (if those messages are grouped into one) and have a "delete thread" item in the popup, which even would speed up the process (no ticking each message separately).